# Have received the following error while reusing movie app in my django project

Tags: python, django

I am using windows 10 python 3.7.3 and django 2.7.2 ,I am new to Django. Want to reuse the movie app "https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/tree/master/basic " in my project.

Steps done before running the manage.py runserver:

1) Copied the folder in my django project directory
2) Have added the app in the Installed apps in Settings.py
3) Have updated the apps url in the urls.py file of my main django project
4) Have checked from the git repo page , no additional dependancy to be downloaded.

```
Error after running manage.py runserver 

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pollsdjango-basic-apps-master'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 577, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 562, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 280, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 286, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 326, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 342, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 241, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 128, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1339, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1161, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You missed a comma in your INSTALLED_APPS after "polls". (However, you don't seem to have followed the installation instructions properly; and that's assuming those would even still work, in a project that hasn't been updated for four years.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks a lot for the help.I have got another error ," from django.db.models import permalink", this is deprecated what can I use instead